# C char array comparison

Tags: c

Let's say I have two char arrays

```
char names[] = { "Jen" , "Will" , "Smith" } ;
char names2[] = {"Sam" , "Will" , "Dave"};
```

and I want to check if both arrays have a common element in a common index
for example both names[] and names2[] have the word "Will" in position 1 (zero based)

I'm trying to do it with this way

```
for(i = 0; i< 3; i++)
{
    if(strcmp(names[i],names2[i]) == 0)
    printf("Same");
}
```

but I'm getting this error "found char where string is expected" any ideas ?

Comment: Well, you have too many parentheses. And you're missing a quote mark after Dave. You're not going to get very far if you come running to SO for every trivial syntax error in your code ... errors that your compiler probably pinpointed.

Comment: You forgot the closing quotes for `"Dave"`.

Comment: @JimBalter yeah , I wrote the code here too fast, in my code it's ok and I'm still getting the error

Comment: Don't write code here, *post* code -- the same code you ran. Otherwise you're wasting your time and ours. We aren't psychic and can't guess what buggy code you actually wrote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

normally in c we declare string as char name[] , if u are creating string array means u r declaration should be char name[][]

Answer (score 2):

`char []` is a `char` array, i.e. a string; what you want is an array of pointers to string literals, so it should be:

```
const char * names[] = { "Jen" , "Will" , "Smith" } ;
const char * names2[] = {"Sam" , "Will" , "Dave"};
```

then the `strcmp` code should compile fine.

Notice that if, instead, you had to work with user-provided strings (and not just string literals) you'd have either to resort to `char * []` and dynamic memory allocation, either to a big bidimensional char array (`char names [STRNUM][STRMAXLENGHT]`).